# How does this recursive function free the tree

Tags: c, recursion, tree, cs50

```c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <cs50.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct node{
        int number;
        struct node* right;
        struct node* left;
    }node;

    void print_tree(node* root);

    int main(void){
        node* tree = NULL;  // creating a starting point

        node* n = malloc(sizeof(node));  // creating the root of the tree
        if(n == NULL){
            return 1;
        }
        n->number = 2;
        n->right = NULL;
        n->left = NULL;
        tree = n;

        n = malloc(sizeof(node));  // creating the right branch
        if(n == NULL){
            return 1;
        }
        n->number = 3;
        n->right = NULL;
        n->left = NULL;
        tree->right = n;

        n = malloc(sizeof(node));  // creating the left branch
        if(n == NULL){
            return 1;
        }
        n->number = 1;
        n->right = NULL;
        n->left = NULL;
        tree->left = n;

        print_tree(tree);  // input tree as a parameter for the function
    }

    void print_tree(node* root){
        if(root == NULL){
            return;
        }
        print_tree(root->left);  // it prints number 1
        printf("%i\n", root->number); // it prints number 2
        print_tree(root->right);  // it prints number 3
        free(root);  // it frees all of them 
    }
```

This code is a tree in C language and I don't have a problem in it. What I am asking is how does the function free these bytes using recursion?
How does it read the function?

Comment: It calls `print_tree(root->left);` which frees the left node. Then it calls `print_tree(root->right);` which frees the right node. Then it calls `free(root);` which frees the current node.

Comment: I would rather ask: why does a function called **print_xy** free any memory. That's a no-go.

Comment: The `print_tree()` function is an abominable mixture of I/O and memory management.  It should be two separate functions, one to print the tree and the other to free the tree.

Comment: Your code comment "// it frees all of them" conveys the probable source of your misunderstanding: it is not a single call to `free()` that frees all the nodes.  Freeing all the nodes takes the joint action of *all* the calls to `free()` performed by *all* the executions of `print_tree()`.  Since you can see from the output that `print_tree()` is called once for each node, it should not be hard to understand that that results in one call to `free()` for each node.

Comment: @JohnBollinger so when execution reads `print_tree(root->left)` it starts the function over with "root->left" to be the parameter of root ?

Comment: Describing it as "start[ing] the function over" is open to misunderstanding.  I'd prefer to say that each recursive call performs a *separate*, *complete* execution of the function with the specified argument.  And, of course, that may include additional recursive calls.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the function print_tree(tree) -> it will call node 1 and 3 from the root in order, the free statement will free the left node, then the right node. Lastly, it frees the node that cause the call of node 1 and 3, which is the root.
You may check this by putting the 'cout' operator after the two recursions call, it will probably print 1 then 3 then 2.